# Structure entry with no URL

Tags: structure

I have an entries Channel with about 100 entries that I need to be able to custom order in CP.  Changing the channel to a structure seems to be a good potential solution for that.   I would also like to have some entries in a "featured" group and then the rest in an "archive" group that would be revealed by a load more button on the index.  Creating top level entries in the structure for "featured" and "archive" seems like it might be a good solution.   My question is, I don't want the "featured" or "archive" entries to have their own url pages (although I guess I could somehow forward them to the index page).  What's the best way to hide or forward these entry pages?   Or is there a better way to achieve the custom ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to create two categories for that and just allow to assign one in the entries. That solves your url problem.

Comment: I thought of that, I would like to be able to sort without going into each individual entry to change the category.  I guess another option would be to leave it a channel section and then make a single section for the index page with a related "feature" field referencing the entries.  Then I could order and add or subtract the featured entries from there

Comment: Sure. On the other side, that's a one time work, I guess.

Comment: I'd agree with this answer. Too often I have seen Craft sites where the sections contain mixed data types, which causes a lot of pain during major site changes because the content was modelled based on the site design instead of the actual content semantics. Organise your content according to what it _is_, not what it looks like or where it goes in the design, and your future self will thank you. My standard sniff-test for whether to create hierarchical Structure sections: "Are these child entries a _more specific_ type of their parent?" If not, then generally relationships are better.